# Don't understand keras double parentheses syntax

Tags: python, keras, syntax

Hi I am new to python and keras and looking in some keran example code:

```
model = VGG19(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
model.trainable=False
x = Flatten(name='flat')(model)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
```

and just don't understand x=Dense(....)(x) what is second paranteses usage? and what is this syntax name if i want to see python doc's?

Comment: Refer to the [Keras Functional API Docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Comment: `Dense` seems to be a class that implements [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__). The first call creates an instance, the seconds calls `.__call__(x)` on the instance.

Comment: no juien I know how to search my question is about python syntax not keras.

Comment: Good question! Dont get the down vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be an easier to understand version of these chained calls:

```
model = VGG19(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
model.trainable=False
layer1 = Flatten(name='flat')(model)
layer2 = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2')(layer2)
layer4 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(layer3)
```

which could be rewritten as:

```
model = VGG19(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
model.trainable=False
model.add( Flatten(name='flat'))
model.add( Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
model.add( Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
model.add( Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))
```

Comment: thanks lenik can you show me a simple python code?

Comment: @pumper see the updated answer

Comment: thanks now i see it